# Rename files by trimming the '\n' at the end of their name

Tags: linux, bash

I made a python script to parse a large volume of some data and save the results which ended up producing ~162 files. The script named these files `Parsed_NameOfOriginal\n`. Notice the `\n` at the end which wasn't intended but was somehow added by my script. Since it took many hours to produce these results I don't want to run the fixed script again.

Is there a way to use the Linux Terminal or a shell script to rename every file in a directory with the same name, but trimming that `\n` at the end?

I.e. `Parsed_ResultA\n` becomes `Parsed_ResultA`.

Note: It's the *new line char* that was added and not a textual `\n`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work:

```
for f in *$'\n'; do mv -i "$f" "${f%$'\n'}"; done
```

- `*$'\n'` expands to all file names ending in a newline character.
- The `for` loop goes through all matching files, saving the file's name in the variable *f*.
- `${f%$'\n'}` strips the trailing newline character from the file name stored in *f*.
- `mv -i` renames the file, prompting if it would overwrite anything.

Comment: Thank you for the very helpful answer. For those who are looking to remove a leading newline character then the following will do the trick: `for f in $'\n'*; do mv -i "$f" "${f#$'\n'}"; done`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the perl renamer from the debian package `libfile-rename-perl`:

```
rename 's/\n//' Parsed_Result*
```

As there are several flavors of `rename` out there, please make a backup of your files before.

Answer (score 0):

OK, OK, my new variant:

```
$ touch boo$'\n'
$ touch foo$'\n'
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 54 Feb  9 12:16 111.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Feb  9 12:17 boo?
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Feb  9 12:17 foo?
$ sh 111.sh 
$ ls -l
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 54 Feb  9 12:16 111.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Feb  9 12:17 boo
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  0 Feb  9 12:17 foo
$ cat 111.sh 
for i in `find ./ -name '*
'`
do
  mv $i$'\n' $i
done
$
```

Old variant(wrong):

Use :

```
find ./ -name "*\n" | sed 's/\(.*\)\\n/mv \1\\\\n\ \1/'
```

to create list of rename commands. And then just copy/paste all these commands to terminal.
Example:

```
$ touch 111\\n
$ touch 222\\n
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  9 11:15 111\n
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  9 11:15 222\n
$ find ./ -name "*\n" | sed 's/\(.*\)\\n/mv \1\\\\n\ \1/'
mv ./111\\n ./111
mv ./222\\n ./222
$ mv ./111\\n ./111
$ mv ./222\\n ./222
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  9 11:15 111 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 0 Feb  9 11:15 222 
$
```

Comment: `\n` is the EOL character, not a literal `\n` as pointed out by the OP. You need `touch foo$'\n'` to create a sample file.

Comment: thanx, I've added new variant for foo$'\n'case.